# G712LWS not turning on after thermal repast

Tags: motherboard, asus-laptop, thermal-paste

As in the first photo, i used first liquid thermal **(Thermal Grizzly Conductonaut Extreme)** on GPU & CPU.

1. Before I did anything I always unplugged the battery first and then did what I wanted to do.
2. The CPU pins are covered already (but i added one more layer of thermal shield) to make sure everything is safe.
3. I added 2 layers of thermal shield to the GPU pins (for the same reason » safety first). And i waited for 3 hours for each layer to completely dry.
4. I made sure everything is clean and no thermals or liquids or anything else on the motherboard.

[The full picture of the motherboard _ G712LWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/One7i.jpg)

[RTX 2070S Pins shield layers / GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na13f.jpg)

However, after turned the laptop on, the keyboard and everything lightened (as always), then it turned off and only **Airplane Light** on the keyboard surface lightened on (white color, continuous lighting, no blubbing).

- I opened the laptop again and I heard a buzz sound from where I marked in the first photo.

[Closer photo for where the buzz sound comes from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj5Rq.jpg)

- *I'm very sure that I didn't mess with anything here in the photo 3*.
- I opened the laptop again and cleaned it one more time and applied **(Thermal Grizzly Kreyonaut Extreme)** instead of the liquid and nothing changed. I still don't understand why there such a sound and why the laptop doesn't turn on anymore.

[THE LIQUID SHIELD PASTE THAT I THE GPU PINS WITH](https://www.motorobit.com/05-ml-gumus-iletken-boya-pcb-devre-tamir-yapiskani)

Comment: Why do you put thermal paste on the pins?

Comment: Your "liquid shield" paste looks like it claims to be electrically conductive which is 100% the opposite of what you want to put on GPU "pins". I assume the "pins" are the capacitors and resistors on top of the GPU in your second image, by shorting them using the paste you have effectively killed it.

Comment: Your motherboard is dead, the past you have used contains silver, a very good current conductor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (at least to me) that you short-circuited something there (buzzing may be overloaded inverter or something).
I don't speak turkish but from the link you sent I assume you used electricaly conductive paste (no idea why you put it to the pins, as this has no effect except short circuiting them)

You probably killed your device but you may be lucky and it survived. Try removing the paste (and don't put it on pins, only on the chip) and powering it on (don't power it on without cooler btw).

You should use thermal conductive paste not electrical conductive

Comment: The good news, I followed your advice step by step, and it worked.

The bad news, either I lost all my data on the main SSD, or there is something wrong with the laptop that it can see one off the SSD's and doesn't see the other one. (I have 2 SSD's installed, you can see both of them in picture 1).

I knew that because once the laptop works it goes immediately to the BIOS, but the first time I turned it on it showed me a screen that something like this was written in it: (S.M.A.R.T unit is damaged or doesn't work well, Press anything to replace it or do backup), and I never saw it again.

Comment: if you have 2 ssd slots try swapping them to check if damafed is ssd or slot (but first check if there isn't any dirt or something which may cause even the second one to die)

Comment: I already tried all of these, right now I'm going to buy another SSD and copy the data from the old SSD to the newer one (the second SSD that i have is also almost full, so I can't copy anything to it). The slots are all fine but the main SSD where the system is installed on seems to be damaged so I'm going to replace it with a new SSD, I will let you know once it's all done.